# Find coords of the largest rectangle in bool array

Tags: arrays, boolean, coordinates

I have a problem.
Let's assume we have a matrix of 1's and 0's and we want to find the largest rectangle in it consists of 1's. The code below does that and computes the area and stores it in the variable "res". My question is, how can I get to the coords of that rectangle in that matrix? I mean something like X,Y,H,W. Where X,Y are start coords and H,W(height,width) is the size of the rectangle. I am kind of lost. Thanks for any reply.

```
       int maximalRectangle(vector<vector<char> > &matrix) 
   {
        int row = matrix.size();
        if (row==0){return 0;}
        int col = matrix[0].size();
        int res=0;
        vector<vector<int>> ones(row,vector<int>(col,0));

        for (int i=0;i<row;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
                if (matrix[i][j]=='1'){ 
                    if (j==0){ones[i][j]=1;}
                    else{ones[i][j]=ones[i][j-1]+1;}
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i=0;i<row;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
                if (ones[i][j]!=0){ 
                    int h = i-1;
                    int tmp=ones[i][j];
                    int mini=ones[i][j];
                    while (h>=0){
                        if (ones[h][j]==0){
                            break;
                        }else{
                            if (ones[h][j]<mini){
                                mini = ones[h][j];
                            }
                            if (tmp< mini*(i-h+1)){
                                tmp= mini*(i-h+1);
                            }
                            h--;
                        }
                    }
                    if (res<tmp){
                        res=tmp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return res;
    }
```